# Redirection / Return Check in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I have a website running in PHP and I have a page (say confirm.php)

And I only want to allow the users who land to confirm.php comes from a page that I specified (e.g. say register.php), may I know is it possible to achieve this?

Regards,
Andy.

Comment: Yes, I did read many place and confirm that HTTP_REFERER is not safe and can be modified easily, or does not defined depending on the User-agent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not rely on the **HTTP REFERER** because users can manipulate it and browsers can refuse to send it.

The only "secure" way would be to set a session variable on register.php and check if that variable is set on confirm.php. Something like this:

register.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
```

confirm.php:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])) {
    die("You did not come from the page i specified!");
}
```

*However*, this will not take into account if the latest page was register.php, BUT that the user have been on register.php.

Because HTTP is stateless, you need to keep track of this at the server level. If you don't have a authenticated user for which you can track all pageviews, this is going to be very hard to implement. How secure do you *really* need it to be?

Comment: This...and it's not hard to create a history stack and keep all pages that are requested allowing you to view what the last pages visited were.

Comment: if you use getenv() instead of $_SERVER variable it cannot be edited later. http://php.net/getenv

Comment: @Arda ... by the programmer. That's not the issue. The problem is the _user_ editing it prior to being sent.

Answer (score 1):

Because HTTP is a stateless protocol, you will need to store the state information server-side.

One method is to store a key into the PHP Session Store, then pass it during redirection, then check it again.

#### register.php

```
<?php
session_start();

// some other code

$_SESSION['stateKey'] = sha1(time() . mt_rand()); // save a randomly created key

header('Location: confirm.php?key=' . $_SESSION['stateKey']);
?>
```

#### confirm.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['stateKey'] == $_GET['key']){
    // pass, do things here
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, and redirect it using `header` or some custom function...

Answer (score 0):

Look at $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERREF'] array in you script to detect from wich page this script was invoked

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

more info: [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: It also says on that same manual page, _"Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted."_