# Ensure paypal return page coming from Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

Further to my question and awesome answers from the previous thread,
[Redirection / Return Check in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266608/)

I would also love to know, if a payment confirmation page is returned to my website from PayPal, how can I 100% sure that it is coming from paypal and the payment is made?

Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the request is coming from PayPal you can try resolving the IP address:

```
if (preg_match('~^(?:.+[.])?paypal[.]com$~', gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) > 0)
{
    // came from PayPal
}
```

You can (and should) also request `https://www[.sandbox].paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr/` with the same data your received in POST and append the `cmd` => `_notify-validate` key-value pair to the request, if the response is `VERIFIED` the data is valid.

See also this question: [PayPal IPN Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856530/paypal-ipn-security)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the remote_addr show the machine IP address instead, any help?

Comment: @cherhan: Which machine? Yours? If so, that's because you're the one requesting the page, and not PayPal.

Comment: @Dugi: Yeah, it does. Cheers!